# Click передача данных

Tags: javascript, vue.js

При клике на div передать только его данные.
[Ссылка на код](http://jsfiddle.net/eywraw8t/343533/)

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
   nationalityName: "",
    nationalityCode: "",
    countries:[
      {
       name: "Aruba",
        code: "AW"
      },
      {
       name: "Australia",
        code: "AU"
      },
      {
       name: "Austria",
        code: "AT"
      },
      {
       name: "Azerbaijan",
        code: "AZ"
      },
      {
       name: "Bahamas",
        code: "BS"
      }
    ]
  },
  methods: {
   toggleClass(e) {
     $(e.currentTarget).children('.option_box').toggleClass('open');
    },
    countryOption(e) {
     var countryName = $(e.target).text();
      var countryCode = $(e.currentTarget).closest('.select').find('.country_code').text();
      this.nationalityName = countryName;
      this.nationalityCode = countryCode;
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.select {
    background: #ccc;
    width: 300px;
    height: 45px;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 0 10px;
}
.option_box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 102%;
  left: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: none;
  background: #777;
  width: 100%;
}
.option_box li {
  padding: 8px 10px;
}
.option_box li:hover {
  background: #ccc;
}
.option_box.open {
  display: block;
}
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div class="select" @click="toggleClass">
    <div class="nationality_input">
      <span class="nationality_val">{{ nationalityName }}</span>
      <input class="input_val" type="hidden" name="Countries"  v-model="nationalityCode">
    </div>
    <ul class="option_box" ref="open"  @click="countryOption">
      <li class="option" v-for="country in countries">
        <span class="country_name">{{ country.name }}</span>
        <span class="country_code hidden">{{ country.code }}</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Уточни пожалуйста, про какой клик идет речь? Про click с методом toggleClass? Или про click с countryOption?

Comment: Когда мы кликаем по <li class="option">

Comment: Просто ты в вопросе написал "при клике на div". Это сбивает с толку.
Я правильно понял, что функция coгntryOption должна получать country как аргумент, при клике на <li/>?

Comment: Кстати название метода как coгntryOption на самое удачное. Назови лучше handleCountryClick

Comment: Да при клике на <li> мы должны получить название страны и ее код, а потом записать эти значения в переменные nationalityName, nationalityCode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так это красиво делается на Vue. Забудьте про jquery, для просвещенных на vue она лишняя)

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    isOpen: false,
   nationalityName: null,
    nationalityCode: null,
    countries:[
      {
       name: "Aruba",
        code: "AW"
      },
      {
       name: "Australia",
        code: "AU"
      },
      {
       name: "Austria",
        code: "AT"
      },
      {
       name: "Azerbaijan",
        code: "AZ"
      },
      {
       name: "Bahamas",
        code: "BS"
      }
    ]
  },
  methods: {
   toggleClass() {
     this.isOpen = !this.isOpen
    },
    countryOption ({ name, code }) {
      this.nationalityName = name;
      this.nationalityCode = code;
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.select {
    background: #ccc;
    width: 300px;
    height: 45px;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 0 10px;
}
.option_box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 102%;
  left: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: none;
  background: #777;
  width: 100%;
}
.option_box li {
  padding: 8px 10px;
}
.option_box li:hover {
  background: #ccc;
}
.option_box.open {
  display: block;
}
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  nationalityName: {{ nationalityName || 'Не известно' }}<br>  
  nationalityCode: {{ nationalityCode || 'Не известно' }}

  <div class="select" @click="toggleClass">
    <div class="nationality_input">
      <span class="nationality_val">{{ nationalityName }}</span>
      <input class="input_val" type="hidden" name="Countries"  v-model="nationalityCode">
    </div>
    <ul :class="{ open: isOpen, option_box: true }">
      <li class="option" v-for="country in countries" @click="countryOption(country)">
        <span class="country_name">{{ country.name }}</span>
        <span class="country_code hidden">{{ country.code }}</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Вот решение твоей задачи

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
   nationalityName: "",
    nationalityCode: "",
    countries:[
      {
       name: "Aruba",
        code: "AW"
      },
      {
       name: "Australia",
        code: "AU"
      },
      {
       name: "Austria",
        code: "AT"
      },
      {
       name: "Azerbaijan",
        code: "AZ"
      },
      {
       name: "Bahamas",
        code: "BS"
      }
    ]
  },
  methods: {
   toggleClass(e) {
     $(e.currentTarget).children('.option_box').toggleClass('open');
    },
    countryOption(e) {
     var countryName = $(e.target).text();
      var countryCode = $(e.currentTarget).closest('.select').find('.country_code').text();
      this.nationalityName = countryName;
      this.nationalityCode = countryCode;
    },
    handleClick({ name, code }) {
      
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div class="select" @click="toggleClass">
    <div class="nationality_input">
      <span class="nationality_val">{{ nationalityName }}</span>
      <input class="input_val" type="hidden" name="Countries"  v-model="nationalityCode">
    </div>
    <ul class="option_box" ref="open"  @click="countryOption">
      <li class="option" v-for="country in countries" @click=handleClick(country)>
        <span class="country_name">{{ country.name }}</span>
        <span class="country_code hidden">{{ country.code }}</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Это написанно с помощю JQ, а можно все это без него? И чисто это гуммано JQ + Vue ?

Comment: @Pavel8289 писать на JQ в последнее время вообще не гуманно) Поэтому надо стараться отказываться от этого шлака и писать нормальный код) В данном примере сохранил код на JQ, так как это не относится к вопросу автора.